# Return of FFMPEG in Background

Tags: php, ffmpeg, proc-open

I am making a code that downloads a list of `m3u8` links by `FFMPEG`

I had this code:

```
function FFMPEG($videocode, $dirvideo) {

    $ffmpeg = '"D:\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe"' . " -hide_banner -loglevel verbose -n -i https://linkplaylist/{$videocode}.m3u8 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy {$dirvideo} 1> log.txt  2>&1";

    exec($ffmpeg, $output, $var);

    return $var;
}

$code = FFMPEG('football', 'football.mp4');

if($code){
    {ERROR CODE}; 
    }else{

    {SUCCESS CODE}
}
```

### Initial problem

And that worked well. I could download the video and know if it was downloaded completely or had some error.

The problem is that this code "hangs" the script in exec () the page is loading until finalize exec () and that of timeout error (shared server) besides being visually strange to the visitor the page loading.

### Resolution of the initial problem

After research I think the solution is to put the code execution in the background so I found this code:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

function FFMPEG($videocode, $dirvideo) {
$cmd = 'start /B D:\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe  -y -i "https://linkplaylist/{$videocode}.m3u8" -map p:0 -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy {$dirvideo}';
proc_close(proc_open ($cmd
,$descriptorspec, $foo));
}
```

### And finally my current problem

And this works fine for the loading and timeout issue, but I can not get a return from when the download was successfully completed.

1 ° proc_open Is this the best solution for my initial problem?

2 ° How can I get a return from when ffmpeg finishes running successfully and the script continues to flow.

### Extra Info

I'm trying to build a solution that works on windows (xampp) but my final server is linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same challenge, and hopefully someone can complete my contribution.

This is only a partial answer that I don't know how to complete for Windows.  The trick is in the pipes apparently, per the ffmpeg [wiki](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options), but the solution is for Unix:

> One more thing to take care about is the standard INPUT (stdin).
>   Command-line ffmpeg tool is designed as an interactive utility that
>   accepts user's input (usually from keyboard) and reports the error log
>   on the user's current screen/terminal. When we run ffmpeg in the
>   background, we want to tell ffmpeg that no input should be accepted
>   (nor waited for) from the stdin. We can tell this to ffmpeg, using I/O
>   redirection again "

I tried using the `-nostdin`, but it had no effect.